# ERROR TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).init is not a function - Angular 6

Tags: angular, highcharts

Following is my code :

import

```
import { HighChartDataParser } from 'app/core/core-service/highchart/highchart-data-parser';
```

TS file

```
   this.TeamchartOptions = this.highChartParser.scoreGauge("solidgauge", this.scoreData.teamScore, this.scoreData.teamScoreColor, this.scoreData.teamScorePercentage);
```

html

```
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">
                                <chart [options]="TeamchartOptions " class="graph"></chart>
                            </div>
```

My highCharts was working correctly but now it gives this error suddenly. I am not clear with Why this is happening, Is there anyone who have come across similar problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, Its a dependancy problem. I simply added `require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);`
to the highschart.ts and It worked

Comment: why does this work?